# Is it better to save a computation and then assign it to an array index or can i do all in one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, runtime

I am trying to solve [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/) (description provided below) problem on leetcode. My previous solution included the line

```
answer[stk_popped_value[1]] = i - stk_popped_value[1]
```

it results in Time Limit Exceeded (TLE) on submission.
However, if I just change that line to

```
            days = i - stk_popped_value[1]
            ans[stk_popped_value[1]] = days
```

It passes without TLE. Why is my initial solution slower? What's happening in python behind the scenes?

---

Problem Description:
Given an array of integers temperatures represents the daily temperatures, return an array answer such that answer[i] is the number of days you have to wait after the ith day to get a warmer temperature. If there is no future day for which this is possible, keep answer[i] == 0 instead.

Constraints:

- 1 <= temperatures.length <= 10^5
- 30 <= temperatures[i] <= 100

Complete solution:

```
ans = [0]*len(temperatures)
stk = []
for i, temp in enumerate(temperatures):
    while stk and stk[-1][0] < temp:
        stk_popped_value = stk.pop()

        days = i - stk_popped_value[1]
        ans[stk_popped_value[1]] = days

    stk.append((temp,i))
return ans
```

Comment: Please include the complete Problem Description here, rather a *link* to external source.

Comment: Timing it with both solutions gives consistent (and expected) results: the version with intermediate variable is *slower*. Probably just bad luck due to the data/load of the machine running the code/whatever...

Comment: @DanielHao Added the description.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille it is quite weird that a slower solution is passing.

Comment: it may very well have been a glitch of the evaluation server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final say on the execution of a piece of code has the *actual* bytecode being executed. So I turned your code into a function:

```
def solve(temperatures):
    ans = [0]*len(temperatures)
    stk = []
    for i, temp in enumerate(temperatures):
        while stk and stk[-1][0] < temp:
            stk_popped_value = stk.pop()

            days = i - stk_popped_value[1]
            ans[stk_popped_value[1]] = days

        stk.append((temp,i))
    return ans
```

And using `dis` standard module for Python 3.9 on Win10 got this:

```
dis.dis(solve)

  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 BUILD_LIST               1
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (temperatures)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (ans)

  4          14 BUILD_LIST               0
             16 STORE_FAST               2 (stk)

  5          18 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (enumerate)
             20 LOAD_FAST                0 (temperatures)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             24 GET_ITER
        >>   26 FOR_ITER                76 (to 104)
             28 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             30 STORE_FAST               3 (i)
             32 STORE_FAST               4 (temp)

  6     >>   34 LOAD_FAST                2 (stk)
             36 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       88
             38 LOAD_FAST                2 (stk)
             40 LOAD_CONST               2 (-1)
             42 BINARY_SUBSCR
             44 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             46 BINARY_SUBSCR
             48 LOAD_FAST                4 (temp)
             50 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             52 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       88

  7          54 LOAD_FAST                2 (stk)
             56 LOAD_METHOD              2 (pop)
             58 CALL_METHOD              0
             60 STORE_FAST               5 (stk_popped_value)

  9          62 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             64 LOAD_FAST                5 (stk_popped_value)
             66 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             68 BINARY_SUBSCR
             70 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             72 STORE_FAST               6 (days)

 10          74 LOAD_FAST                6 (days)
             76 LOAD_FAST                1 (ans)
             78 LOAD_FAST                5 (stk_popped_value)
             80 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             82 BINARY_SUBSCR
             84 STORE_SUBSCR
             86 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           34

 12     >>   88 LOAD_FAST                2 (stk)
             90 LOAD_METHOD              3 (append)
             92 LOAD_FAST                4 (temp)
             94 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             96 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             98 CALL_METHOD              1
            100 POP_TOP
            102 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           26

 13     >>  104 LOAD_FAST                1 (ans)
            106 RETURN_VALUE
```

Compared to the following bytecode for the version without an intermediate value:

```
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 BUILD_LIST               1
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (temperatures)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (ans)

  4          14 BUILD_LIST               0
             16 STORE_FAST               2 (stk)

  5          18 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (enumerate)
             20 LOAD_FAST                0 (temperatures)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             24 GET_ITER
        >>   26 FOR_ITER                72 (to 100)
             28 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             30 STORE_FAST               3 (i)
             32 STORE_FAST               4 (temp)

  6     >>   34 LOAD_FAST                2 (stk)
             36 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       84
             38 LOAD_FAST                2 (stk)
             40 LOAD_CONST               2 (-1)
             42 BINARY_SUBSCR
             44 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             46 BINARY_SUBSCR
             48 LOAD_FAST                4 (temp)
             50 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             52 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       84

  7          54 LOAD_FAST                2 (stk)
             56 LOAD_METHOD              2 (pop)
             58 CALL_METHOD              0
             60 STORE_FAST               5 (stk_popped_value)

  9          62 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             64 LOAD_FAST                5 (stk_popped_value)
             66 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             68 BINARY_SUBSCR
             70 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             72 LOAD_FAST                1 (ans)
             74 LOAD_FAST                5 (stk_popped_value)
             76 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             78 BINARY_SUBSCR
             80 STORE_SUBSCR
             82 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           34

 11     >>   84 LOAD_FAST                2 (stk)
             86 LOAD_METHOD              3 (append)
             88 LOAD_FAST                4 (temp)
             90 LOAD_FAST                3 (i)
             92 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             94 CALL_METHOD              1
             96 POP_TOP
             98 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           26

 12     >>  100 LOAD_FAST                1 (ans)
            102 RETURN_VALUE
```

The crucial difference is:

```
72 STORE_FAST               6 (days)

 10          74 LOAD_FAST                6 (days)
```

Which are additional operations in the first approach (intermediate variable `days`) related to storing the value and loading from it. So it is highly unlikely that intermediate value repetitively gave better timings.